# Spawning a docker command yields an empty result

Tags: go

I have the following Go code, where I try to spawn `docker` command and get its output:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os/exec"

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("docker")
    cmdOutput, err := cmd.Output()
    if (err != nil) {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(cmdOutput))
}
```

But when I run this code as a result I get an empty string, which is stange since I get an output when I run `docker` command directly in a command line.

Moreover, this same code yields results just fine if I spawn other commands with it, for example `ls`.

What may be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [using cmd.CombinedOutput()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.CombinedOutput)

Comment: I suggest posting a link to the godoc for the command. Maybe explain why it works as well. I just can't bring myself to upvote a 3 word answer...